# Does Not Include Specified Expression as Part of Aggregate Function

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I've researched this issue but can't figure out what exactly it is that I'm doing wrong.  I have the following SQL code in an Access Query.

```
SELECT [Age and Info Report].[Approval Status]
FROM [Age and Info Report]
GROUP BY [Age and Info Report].[Approval Status]
HAVING ((([Age and Info Report].[Approval Status])="Pending"));
```

I keep getting this error:

> You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified
>   expression '[Age and Info Report].[Approval Status]="Pending" as part
>   of an aggregate function.

The Approval Status field has text strings that read Approved, Pending, or Rejected.  I just want to return the Pending and a count of the Pending items, but I can't get past just using "Pending" as the criteria.

Comment: You took the time to ask the question. Courtesy would be to award me points for the answer I took the time to provided you with. Unless you feel it falls short of what you needed. Just saying.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, I've reduced your expression to this:

```
select
      x
from y
group by
      x
having 
      x = "Pending";
```

And the problem is it appears you'd rather have this:

```
select
      x
    , count(*) as PendingCount
from y
where 
    x = "Pending"
group by
    x
```

Having is used to say thing more like

```
having count(*) > Q
```

And that would tell you which items, after grouping, were found to have occurred more than Q times in the original data.

**where** applies a filter to the records selected *before* they are aggregated. **having** applies a filter (which must be stated as some sort of aggregation filter, such as count() ) to the results *after* they've been aggregated.